# Subexponential algorithms that apply only one of factoring and discrete logarithm?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, computational-number-theory, factorization, cryptography

Shor (quantum polynomial), Number Field Sieve (subexponential), Pollard rho (square root) all have both factoring and discrete logarithm over $\mathbb F_p^*$ variants.

> What are the subexponential techniques that only applies to
>
> 1. balanced semiprime integer factoring but not to discrete logarithm over **some known** cryptographically important structures including $\mathbb F_p^*$ and Elliptic Curve Discrete Logarithm?
> 2. balanced semiprime integer factoring but not to discrete logarithm over **all known** cryptographically important structures including $\mathbb F_p^*$ and Elliptic Curve Discrete Logarithm?
> 3. discrete logarithm over **some known** cryptographically important structure including $\mathbb F_p^*$ but not to balanced semiprime integer factoring?

Please provide references appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Lenstra's ECM method is, in the worst case ($N = pq$ with $p < q$ both primes of the same size), $L_p(1/2)$ (see H. W. Lenstra, Jr., *Factoring integers with elliptic curves*, Ann. of Math. (2) vol. 126 no. 3 (1987): 649-37).  ECM cannot be used to solve discrete logs in elliptic curves or finite fields, so I think this answers 1. and 2.

For 3., there are subexponential finite-field-discrete-log-specific algorithms (like Adleman's Function Field Sieve, for example, or more recently the Barbulescu-Gaudry-Joux-Thomé quasipolynomial algorithm), but they apply to small- and medium-characteristic extension fields, not $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$.